# fonts are not saved on deploying on vercel next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

What I see locally:

[image]

And what I see on deploying:

[image]

Even a layout doesn't save fonts. It is a dynamic page though (/profile/[id].jsx)
On building I don't use next export. Ofc I also use className, .module.css files. The bug works only on this dynamic page. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using the @import directive then try linking the fonts using <link>

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom `document` to link the fonts. This way your fonts are available everywhere in the app. They are loaded even before the styles to avoid font jump when the styles load.

The _document.js file:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          {/* link your fonts here */}
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Read more on custom document [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) at well explained Vercel Docs. I hope it helps!